# Converting one alphabet to another

Tags: c#

I am preparing a simple dictionary project and I have prepared it to search in 2 languages. Still, as one of them is using Cyrillic letters, I have to be able to check in the database, even if the word is written in Latin letters. What do I mean

in Cyrillic: кон

in Latin: kon

Both should give the description of the word (in this case "horse"). I have been thinking of using two structures with two alphabets in order to achieve this....Still somehow I cannot get it. Does some of you have experience in a similar situation? If yes - please share an advice or code-sample.

Comment: Please don't repeat the tags ("C#") in the title. That's what the tags are for.

Comment: Thank for the edit. I did not know that the system works like this. My bad!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A Dictionary should be suitable for mapping cyrillic characters to latin ones. I'll assume you're going to follow http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_9 to map them.

```
public class ISO9TransliterationProvider {
    private readonly Dictionary<Char, Char> charMapping = new Dictionary<char,char>() {
        { 'А', 'A' }, 
        { 'Б', 'B' } 
        //etc.
    };

    public string ToLatin(string cyrillic) {
        StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
        foreach (char c in cyrillic)
            result.Append(charMapping[c]);
        return result.ToString();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this is of help to you:

[Windows Transliteration Services](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd374080.aspx)

Comment: Was there a particular reason you posted an old version of that link?

Comment: Oops. No, that wasn't my intention.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, still using this method for simple project as the one that I am working on would be too much :) Still this will come in handy in another project to come, so thanks again ;)

Answer (score 0):

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace Transliter
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        Dictionary<string, string> words = new Dictionary<string, string>();

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            words.Add("а", "a");
            words.Add("б", "b");
            words.Add("в", "v");
            words.Add("г", "g");
            words.Add("д", "d");
            words.Add("е", "e");
            words.Add("ё", "yo");
            words.Add("ж", "zh");
            words.Add("з", "z");
            words.Add("и", "i");
            words.Add("й", "j");
            words.Add("к", "k");
            words.Add("л", "l");
            words.Add("м", "m");
            words.Add("н", "n");
            words.Add("о", "o");
            words.Add("п", "p");
            words.Add("р", "r");
            words.Add("с", "s");
            words.Add("т", "t");
            words.Add("у", "u");
            words.Add("ф", "f");
            words.Add("х", "h");
            words.Add("ц", "c");
            words.Add("ч", "ch");
            words.Add("ш", "sh");
            words.Add("щ", "sch");
            words.Add("ъ", "j");
            words.Add("ы", "i");
            words.Add("ь", "j");
            words.Add("э", "e");
            words.Add("ю", "yu");
            words.Add("я", "ya");
            words.Add("А", "A");
            words.Add("Б", "B");
            words.Add("В", "V");
            words.Add("Г", "G");
            words.Add("Д", "D");
            words.Add("Е", "E");
            words.Add("Ё", "Yo");
            words.Add("Ж", "Zh");
            words.Add("З", "Z");
            words.Add("И", "I");
            words.Add("Й", "J");
            words.Add("К", "K");
            words.Add("Л", "L");
            words.Add("М", "M");
            words.Add("Н", "N");
            words.Add("О", "O");
            words.Add("П", "P");
            words.Add("Р", "R");
            words.Add("С", "S");
            words.Add("Т", "T");
            words.Add("У", "U");
            words.Add("Ф", "F");
            words.Add("Х", "H");
            words.Add("Ц", "C");
            words.Add("Ч", "Ch");
            words.Add("Ш", "Sh");
            words.Add("Щ", "Sch");
            words.Add("Ъ", "J");
            words.Add("Ы", "I");
            words.Add("Ь", "J");
            words.Add("Э", "E");
            words.Add("Ю", "Yu");
            words.Add("Я", "Ya");
    }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string source = textBox1.Text;
            foreach (KeyValuePair<string, string> pair in words)
            {
                source = source.Replace(pair.Key, pair.Value);
            }
            textBox2.Text = source;
        }
    }
}
```

cryllic to latin:

```
text.Replace(pair.Key, pair.Value);
```

latin to cryllic

```
source.Replace(pair.Value,pair.Key);
```